# Code structure for event thread and main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I'd appreciate some advice on program design. I've got a swing GUI that I initiate from the main by:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new GUI(generations);
    }
});
```

However, as some of the main processing takes a while I want to do most of the processing in the main thread (or maybe a separate one started by the main?). Do I need to create an instance of GUI and then call its methods from main?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You're question is a bit vague.  Are you saying that your GUI class does a lot of work that could be done in the background while it shows its UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create initial state of GUI - the same way as you are doing now, with empty visual elements, then compute their content on the main thread, and then send updates to the visual elements the same way with `invokeLater()`.

One problem is how to access GUI elements from the main thread. Possiible solution is as follows:

```
class GUI extends JFrame {
    JTextArea jlist = new JTextArea();

    public GUI(CompletableFuture<GUI> result) {
        this.add(jlist, null);
        result.complete(this);
    }

    public void print(String m) {
        jlist.append(m);
    }

}

public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<GUI> result = new CompletableFuture();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new GUI(result));
    GUI gui = result.get();
    // compute something
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // pass computed value to GUI
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> gui.print("time="+time));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Alexei has answered my question, thanks for that. Are swing worker threads no longer used?

Comment: @John since the class SwingWorker still exists, it is used by somebody :). But in your case, it would not make the code more compact or readable.